# how to find operating system label using command line

Tags: command-line, command, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

like we have %windir% which returns the C;\windows , do we have any command that returns only  the operating system drive letter ('C') ?

I tried the command "label" but it returns more than the label info..

Comment: On Linux, it's super simple: `return "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, try these:

```
1. %SystemDrive%
2. %HOMEDRIVE%
```

The first gives you the drive letter that holds your system files, the second gives you drive letter that holds your documents.

Answer (score 2):

WMIC.exe allows you to make WMI queries from the command line.

```
wmic os get systemdrive
```

will tell you the same thing as %SystemDrive%, though you can also use it for InstallDate, SystemDirectory (i.e. %WINDIR%\System32, though I don't recall ever having seen a machine with a different name for that directory), LastBootupTime, etc.

The output isn't necessarily easy to parse from a script, but if you just want to see the info, it's very useful.